# Как наклонить текст на бок в ячейке таблицы?

Tags: html, css

Доброго времени всем суток.

На простую задачку уже убил 3 дня... в общем, как наклонить текст набок, ну, скажем, на левый? (Так, что бы если положить голову на левое плече, удобно было читать.)

Без явы, без всяких библиотек, с помощью стиля, но не с CSS файлом, а допустим в ячейке таблицы, уже после `class='*'` дописать `style...` (если так нельзя то, как можно более простым методом).

p.s.
пользуясь случаем, поздравляю всех программистов с профессиональным праздником, сегодня не 13 сентября, а 256 января, как должен считать любой программер! с праздником!

Comment: Только флэш. Мб хтмл5 умеет, не уверен.

Comment: > уже после class='*' дописать style
> 

style - это и есть css, только в html.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

При помощи CSS - только некроссбраузерным методом: надо написать четыре строчки:

```
-webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg); 
-moz-transform: rotate(-90deg);
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=3);
-o-transform: rotate(-90deg);
```

Более логичный способ - SVG, но и тут все сложно: IE с ним не очень дружит, придется использовать связку SVG+VRML.
Короче: картинку юзайте. =)

Comment: ок, спс, только жаль на IE не работает (поворот в другую сторону)